# On Windows, is there a way to open selected text as a folder?

Tags: windows, context-menu

For example, say I have the text somewhere (Notepad, Word...):

> Go to directory **C:\Program Files**, then...

I'd like to select what's in bold, right-click and have a menu item saying "**Go to C:\Program Files**".

Is there any extension for (or maybe a Windows way of) having this?

Comment: I don't know a way to achieve exactly what you want, but of course you can copy the 'bold' text (CTRL+C), open a File Explorer window, paste (CTRL+V) this text into the address bar and press Enter...

Comment: Thanks :-). Obviously, that's exactly what I'm trying to find a short version for.

Comment: You can also copy the text then do Windows Key+R then Ctrl+V and Enter. Slightly faster. I don't think you're going to find a way to add this to the context menu, because they're different context menus in different programs. You'd need to modify Notepad itself or Word itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone has made an app to do exactly what you're describing (I'm not aware of any), then the solution would like involve coding or scripting.

As I understand the question there are 2 parts:

1) How to accomplish opening a path from some selected bit of text

2) How to add #1 to a context menu.

**For #1 (scripting the action):**

This could be done programmatically from a number of languages. Personally, I would use an Autohotkey script, but it could be done other ways.

The below script worked for me under Autohotkey L (1.1) which can be found here
https://www.autohotkey.com/download/

Currently, I have it bound to the F3 key. But it could be adjusted to any key based on syntax here:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

**Install AHK_L and then save as openSelPath.ahk:**

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; test folder D:\Downloads
; test file D:\Dev\YOmDuDV.jpg
; no-existent path D:\Dev\doesnotexist.foo

~F3::
    openSelectedPath()
    return



openSelectedPath() {
    send, ^c
    sleep, 200
    strPath := Clipboard 
    intLen := StrLen(strPath)
    if ( intLen > 0) {
        ;check if path exists
        strResult := FileExist(strPath)
        if ( "" == strResult) {
            msgbox, 48, Error:, Path "%strPath%" not found.
            return
        }
        isDir := (0 != InStr(strResult, "D"))
        if ( 1 == isDir ) {
            Run, explorer.exe "%strPath%"
            return
        }

        intLastSlash := InStr(strPath, "\", false, 0)
        if ( 0 == intLastSlash ) {
            msgbox, 48, Error:, Path "%strPath%" not found.
            return
        }
        strParentDir := SubStr(strPath, 1, intLastSlash- 1)

        ;check if path exists
        strResult := FileExist(strParentDir)
        if ( "" == strResult) {
            msgbox, 48, Error:, Path "%strParentDir%" not found.
            return
        }
        isDir := (0 != InStr(strResult, "D"))
        if ( 1 == isDir ) {
            Run, explorer.exe "%strParentDir%"
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

**For #2 (adding to a context menu):**

I see that one of the tags is 'context-menu'... I will admit, I'm not sure that you would do this from a context menu; based off the description it sounds like you would like to do this directly from notepad/wordpad/etc. *Support for context-menus is program-specific.*

I don't think you would be able to access it from a context menu for any Microsoft apps (Notepad/Wordpad/Word/Excel/etc) since they are closed source. You could maybe do some plugins for the Office apps, but I believe that requires programming.

I know some open-source apps like Notepad++ support defining shortcuts via XML etc (I think context menu options may be supported in NPP as well, but that might require writing a plugin in C++).

If you are talking Windows Explorer/File Explorer, it is possible to add context menu verbs in but it wouldn't make sense to me to do so for this scenario because you would presumably be launching from some other program.

Comment: Auto hot key is just fine (and even better). Thanks.